# Call external native API function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, native, ffi

Some Flutter framework classes use native external functions that are binded at compile time for use by the system.

I take the `RootIsolateToken` class as an example, but it applies to all those that refer to external functions with the symbol `PlatformConfigurationNativeApi::<name_reference>`

```
/// A token that represents a root isolate.
class RootIsolateToken {
   RootIsolateToken._(this._token);

   /// An enumeration representing the root isolate (0 if not a root isolate).
   final int _token;

   /// The token for the root isolate that is executing this Dart code. If this
   /// Dart code is not executing on a root isolate [instance] will be null.
   static final RootIsolateToken? instance = () {
     final int token = __getRootIsolateToken();
     return token == 0 ? null : RootIsolateToken._(token);
   }();

   @FfiNative<Int64 Function()>(
       'PlatformConfigurationNativeApi::GetRootIsolateToken')
   external static int __getRootIsolateToken();
}
```

If I instantiate the class I get the result which is finally given by the `__getRootIsolateToken` function.

I would like to use that kind of native function directly for several reasons.

Copying the affected piece of code to change is not a solution in this case because some of it is external.

So the questions are two:

1. Given that the mentioned function is reserved for the class obviously I can't call it externally even if it is static, how is it possible to call the native function that underlies it using its textual symbol?
2. How could you make a new declaration to compile the native function, even if succeeding would cause the system to compile that function again?

If I use the below code in my own class:

```
   @FfiNative<Int64 Function()>(
       'PlatformConfigurationNativeApi::GetRootIsolateToken')
   external static int __getRootIsolateToken();
```

I get the error:

> *Invalid argument(s): Couldn't resolve native function
> 'PlatformConfigurationNativeApi::GetRootIsolateToken' in 'package:...' : undefined symbol: PlatformConfigurationNativeApi::GetRootIsolateToken.*

Flutter 3.7.3 • stable channel • Dart 2.19.2